# How to process the latest file from SharePoint in Synapse pipeline

Tags: sharepoint, azure-synapse

I'm building the pipeline to process the latest file on SharePoint in synapse, but I have no idea that how to process only the latest.
I think 3 steps are needed in the pipeline.(but now I have not added third activity yet.)
[image: pipeine]
First is "Get access token from SharePoint" and this is succeed.
Second is "Get the list of files" and this is also succeed.
And the last one is "Select only the latest file" but I have no idea how should I do.
I tried to use `@item().value.TimeLastModified` from output of the second step.
[image: second step output]

The update frequency of the data is almost monthly but the file name pattern is not the same every month. (not like filename_yyyyMM.xlsx)
So it is hard to select the file that I want to process from filename.

Do you have any idea? Any answer would be helped.
Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to take only the latest file from the list of files( from step:2)

Comment: yes but i have no idea what should i  do.

Answer (score 0):

After getting files list from your second web activity, you can follow the below approach to achieve your requirement.

Like your web activity output array, I took a sample array of filenames and last modified dates like below. I have stored this in a pipeline parameter of array type.

```
[
    {
        "filename":"file1.xlsx",
        "TimeLastModified":"2023-11-16T01:37:20Z"
    },
    {
        "filename":"file2.xlsx",
        "TimeLastModified":"2023-11-17T01:37:20Z"
    },
    {
        "filename":"file3.xlsx",
        "TimeLastModified":"2023-10-16T01:24:20Z"
    }
]
```

First create two variables in the pipeline, `date` and `latest_filename` of string type.

Give an old date as starting value to the `date` variable. We will compare the current last modified date in a loop to this variable and if its greater, then update this variable with current modified date.

So, give old date, here I am giving last year date `@subtractFromTime(utcnow(),1,'year')`.

[image]

Then, give your web activity output array `@activity('get the list of files').output.value` to ForEach and make sure to check the **Sequential**. Here I have given my array parameter.

[image]

Inside ForEach, take an if activty and use below expression to compare the dates.

```
@greaterOrEquals(ticks(item().TimeLastModified), ticks(variables('date')))
```

[image]

Inside **True activities**, use set variable activities to update the `date` and `latest_filename` variables to current filename and current `TimeLastModified`.

[image]

Update your current filename.

[image]

Debug the pipeline and the filename which has latest modified date will be stored in the `latest_filename` variable at the end of For loop.

[image]

Use this variable for the further steps as per your requirement.